# Does a Mundane Arrow Fired From a Magical Bow Count as a Magical Weapon Attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, weapons, ranged-attack, ammunition

I've seen this question asked in previous editions, but I want to ask this question specifically for D&D 5e. Apparently there is still some debate about this. If I am a fighter with a +2 bow and I fire a nonmagical, mundane arrow at an enemy (golem, for example) that has resistance to damage from nonmagical weapons, does my attack overcome the damage resistance?

Comment: Related: [What makes a weapon magical, for the purpose of immunity to non-magical weapons?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/84511/what-makes-a-weapon-magical-for-the-purpose-of-immunity-to-non-magical-weapons)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

#### YES, a mundane arrow fired from a magical bow overcomes the resistance

In the D&D 5e Errata, this issue is addressed:

> Magic Weapons (p. 140). The section ends with a new paragraph: “If a magic weapon has the ammunition property, ammunition fired from it is considered magical for the purpose of overcoming resistance and immunity to nonmagical attacks and damage.”

Here are some additional reasons:

1. [Jeremy Crawford says so.](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/542134997830733824) If this isn't enough reason for you, please
   read on.
2. In the weapons table in the PHB (p. 149), 1d8 is listed as the
   damage for a longbow, not for an arrow. Bows are weapons that
   specify that they require ammunition, and arrows are ammunition, not
   weapons.
3. The resistance is against "bludgeoning, piercing, and slashing from
   nonmagical weapons" and if a +1 bow is a magical weapon, the damage
   bypasses resistance since it is from a magical weapon.
4. A single +1 arrow is in the rarity category "uncommon", just like +1
   bows. If an archer is relying on +1 arrows to be as relevant in
   combat against a nonmagic-weapon-resistance enemy as a melee fighter
   with a +1 weapon, the archer is only going to have a handful of
   one-off shots for their entire career if item rarities are followed
   from the 5e DMG. This will severely limit bow users at later levels
   while melee users and casters are able to do full damage. The
   alternative is that the DM has to give out stacks of +1 arrows,
   which breaks the suggested occurrence of magical items.
5. According to the "Effective Hit Points Based On Resistances and
   Immunities" table on page 277 of the DMG, as CR increases, the
   effective hitpoint multiplier of a monster with immunities and
   resistances decreases. The claim made in the text above this table
   is that the change is because, as characters increase in level, they
   should have access to better means of bypassing the resistance or
   immunity. In the case of an archer, the small collection of magical
   arrows that they may collect in their career (again, as per rarity
   suggestions in the DMG) may last a couple of encounters, but doesn't
   represent "the means to counteract that resistance or immunity"
   after more than a couple of encounters with relatively common
   creatures at higher levels (basically anything incorporeal, many
   elementals, many constructs, many creatures of magical nature).

Comment: that and... if magical ranged weapons -didn't- transfer their properties to their fired ammunition, what would even be the point? what would you do with a +3 sling, flap the leather strings at them? walk up and whack enemies in the face with the +2 bow itself?

Comment: Note that the MM resistances have generally been errataed to be to "nonmagical attacks", instead of "nonmagical weapons". This makes it even more definite that if either the arrow or the bow is magical, the attack is magical.